# Prevent moveRowAtIndexPath beyond fixed index

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController displaying dynamic table data with an additional row at the end (using a separate cell prototype) containing an 'Add' button.

I'd like for users to be able to re-order the table rows but prevent them from moving a row to a point *after* the last row.

I've implemented:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

    return indexPath.row != elements.count

}
```

To prevent users moving the 'Add' table row

and am also testing for

```
    if(toIndexPath.row < library.regularTasks.count)
```

inside

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

which prevents the rows being swapped **in the model**.

However I can't see a way to prevent the rows being dragged beyond the last row **in the UI**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

I used:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath {  
// Test whether destination is allowed    
if(proposedDestinationIndexPath.row < elements.count){
      return proposedDestinationIndexPath // if allowed move to proposed destination
    }else{
        return sourceIndexPath // if not, send back to where it came from!
    } 
}
```